# Press any key to continue from another script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm struggling more than I expected with this "simple" problem. I have two scripts, "one" and "two". "Two" calls "one" and reads its output line by line, and at one point "one" waits for input. How can I make "two" simulate a keypress to continue?
No matter what I try it gets stuck with the "Press any key to continue" message.

**one.sh:**

```
echo pre
echo "Press any key to continue"
read -n 1 -s -r -p ""
echo post
```

**two.sh:**

```
{
    while read -r line; do
    echo $line
    if echo $line | grep "Press enter" &> /dev/null; then
        printf "\r"
    fi
    done
} < <(./one.sh)
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

**Edit:**

I fixed it by using named pipes, as Todd A. Jacobs suggested. Scripts look like this:

**one.sh:**

```
mkfifo mypipe
echo pre
echo "Press any key to continue"
read -n 1 -s -r -p ""<mypipe
echo post
```

**two.sh:**

```
{
    while read -r line; do
    echo $line
    if echo $line | grep "Press enter" &> /dev/null; then
        echo >mypipe
    fi
    done
} < <(./one.sh)
```

Comment: You might want to look at `expect` instead of a bash script

Comment: You could build a Bash script that uses named pipes as a control channel, or checking each other's standard error, or switching standard input around between iterations, but if you want interaction use Expect instead.

Comment: I didn't know about named pipes, but that did the trick! I also could use expect, of course, it looks powerful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe the input to `one.sh` from `two.sh`. See an example below.

**one.sh**

```
echo "Running one.sh...";
echo "Enter your name: ";
read name;
echo "Hello $name..!!";
echo "End one.sh";
```

**two.sh**

```
echo "Running two.sh...";
name=World
echo $name | ./one.sh;
echo "End two.sh";
```

However, if your application (`two.sh`) needs to make several interactions with another command line application (`one.sh`), then you can use [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

> and at one point "one" waits for input

If one.sh just expects exactly one keystroke you can pipe something out to it...

```
{ ...
} < <(echo y | ./one.sh)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care what the user presses to continue just use pause. It pauses the script until the user presses a button.

```
echo "Press any key to continue"
pause
echo post
```

Comment: The thing is that I can modify the script "two.sh", but not "one.sh".

Comment: Not sure about that one then. Don't really know of ways to send a key input to another script... Good luck with this though